# Wordnet Lemmatizer for R

Tags: r, nlp, wordnet, lemmatization

I would like to use the `wordnet` lemmatizer to lemmatize the words in `a`

```
> a<-c("He saw a see-saw on a sea shore", "she is feeling cold")
> a
[1] "He saw a see-saw on a sea shore" "she is feeling cold"
```

I convert `a` into a corpus and do pre-processing steps (like stopword removal, lemmatization etc)

```
> a <- Corpus(VectorSource(a))
```

I wanted to do the lemmatization in the below way,

```
> filter <- getTermFilter("ExactMatchFilter", a, TRUE)
> terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 1, filter)
> sapply(terms, getLemma)
```

but I get this error

```
> filter <- getTermFilter("ExactMatchFilter", a, TRUE)
Error in .jnew(paste("com.nexagis.jawbone.filter", type, sep = "."), word,  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

My idea is to lemmatize the whole corpus and not a single word, How can it be accomplished?

Comment: Not entirely sure about using R for interacting with WordNet or any NLP facility, but what I'd do here is use rpy to accomplish the R business and use NLTK for the WordNet/lemmatization stuff.  Granted this works UNLESS your code HAS to be in R for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Put you code in a loop, you can try something like this:

```
       lapply(a,function(x){
            x.filter <- getTermFilter("ExactMatchFilter", x, TRUE))
            terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 1, x.filter)
            sapply(terms, getLemma)
         })
```

Comment: For some reason this code with OP's data gives me list with two elements that are empty lists. What am I missing ?