# How to perform Lemmatization in R?

Tags: r, nlp, lemmatization

This question is a possible duplicate of **[Lemmatizer in R or python (am, are, is -> be?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993796/lemmatizer-in-r-or-python-am-are-is-be)**, but I'm adding it again since the previous one was closed saying it was too broad and the only answer it has is not efficient (as it accesses an external website for this, which is too slow as I have very large corpus to find the lemmas for). So a part of this question will be similar to the above mentioned question.

According to Wikipedia, lemmatization is defined as:

> Lemmatisation (or lemmatization) in linguistics, is the process of grouping together the different inflected forms of a word so they can be analysed as a single item.

A simple Google search for lemmatization in R will *only* point to the package `wordnet` of R. When I tried this package expecting that a character vector `c("run", "ran", "running")` input to the lemmatization function would result in `c("run", "run", "run")`, I saw that this package only provides functionality similar to `grepl` function through various filter names and a dictionary.

An example code from `wordnet` package, which gives maximum of 5 words starting with "car", as the filter name explains itself:

```
filter <- getTermFilter("StartsWithFilter", "car", TRUE)
terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 5, filter)
sapply(terms, getLemma)
```

The above is **NOT** the lemmatization that I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is, using `R` I want to find true roots of the words: (For e.g. from `c("run", "ran", "running")` to `c("run", "run", "run")`).

Comment: sorry, but I think this is "looking for a package or tool" -- *not* trying to solve a particular programming problem.  Maybe there are computational linguistics/text-mining forums you could ask on?

Comment: I think this question is slightly different than the the typical package/tool-searching questions that get close. It's asking how to perform lemmatization in R, which is a programming question.

@StrikeR : I suggest you change the last line "Is there ... " in order to avoid this question getting closed.

Comment: @ChthonicProject thanks for the suggestion. Made changes accordingly.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. The programming part of this has a simple answer - find/create a dictionary and perform a lookup.

Comment: @eddi I disagree with your comment that this isn't a programming question. In your comment, you are assuming that there is only one form of lemmatization using dictionary look up, but there are also other forms which are rule based. So, I guess the programming part is not as simple as you think it is. I'm fine with any answer which can perform lemmatization, specifically in R, be it a dictionary based or rule based. But only constraint is that, it should not be slow to process a huge text corpus.

Comment: @StrikeR ok, so are you having trouble implementing those rules? *That* would be a programming question. Are you having trouble implementing a dictionary based solution? That would also be a programming question. This is neither.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Hello you can try package [`koRpus`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/koRpus/index.html) which allow to use [Treetagger](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) :

```
tagged.results <- treetag(c("run", "ran", "running"), treetagger="manual", format="obj",
                      TT.tknz=FALSE , lang="en",
                      TT.options=list(path="./TreeTagger", preset="en"))
tagged.results@TT.res

##     token tag lemma lttr wclass                               desc stop stem
## 1     run  NN   run    3   noun             Noun, singular or mass   NA   NA
## 2     ran VVD   run    3   verb                   Verb, past tense   NA   NA
## 3 running VVG   run    7   verb Verb, gerund or present participle   NA   NA
```

See the `lemma` column for the result you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks Victor. That answer helped me. But I'm still working on it. Would like to wait for 2 more days to look for any other solutions and accept this if no better answer is given.

Comment: No problem, I understand, use an external software can be tricky.

Answer (score 23):

As a previous post mentioned, the function lemmatize_words() from the R package textstem can perform this and give you what I understand as your desired results:

```
library(textstem)
vector <- c("run", "ran", "running")
lemmatize_words(vector)

## [1] "run" "run" "run"
```

Answer (score 9):

@Andy and @Arunkumar are correct when they say **textstem** library can be used to perform stemming and/or lemmatization. However, lemmatize_words() will only work on a vector of words. But in a corpus, we do not have vector of words; we have strings, with each string being a document's content. Hence, to perform lemmatization on a corpus, you can use function lemmatize_strings() as an argument to tm_map() of **tm** package.

```
> corpus[[1]]
[1] " earnest roughshod document serves workable primer regions recent history make 
terrific th-grade learning tool samuel beckett applied iranian voting process bard 
black comedy willie loved another trumpet blast may new mexican cinema -bornin "
> corpus <- tm_map(corpus, lemmatize_strings)
> corpus[[1]]
[1] "earnest roughshod document serve workable primer region recent history make 
terrific th - grade learn tool samuel beckett apply iranian vote process bard black 
comedy willie love another trumpet blast may new mexican cinema - bornin"
```

Do not forget to run the following line of code after you have done lemmatization:

```
> corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

This is because in order to create a document-term matrix, you need to have 'PlainTextDocument' type object, which gets changed after you use lemmatize_strings() (to be more specific, the corpus object does not contain content and meta-data of each document anymore - it is now just a structure containing documents' content; this is not the type of object that DocumentTermMatrix() takes as an argument).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) is enough for you? Typical natural language processing tasks make do with stemmed texts. You can find several packages from CRAN Task View of NLP: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html

If you really do require something more complex, then there's specialized solutsions based on mapping sentences to neural nets. As far as I know, these require massive amount of training data. There is lots of open software created and made available by [Stanford NLP Group](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml).

If you really want to dig into the topic, then you can dig through the event archives linked at the same Stanford NLP Group [publications](http://nlp.stanford.edu/publications.shtml) section. There's some books on the topic as well.

Comment: Stemming is what I'm currently using for my corpus, but what I'm really looking for is lemmatization and I want to compare how well the results are going to be improved (sceptical) when I use lemmatization in place of stemming. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answers are a bit outdated here. You should be using R package udpipe now - available at https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=udpipe - see https://github.com/bnosac/udpipe or docs at https://bnosac.github.io/udpipe/en

Notice the difference between the word meeting (NOUN) and the word meet (VERB) in the following example when doing lemmatisation and when doing stemming, and the annoying screwing up of the word 'someone' to 'someon' when doing stemming.

```r
library(udpipe)
x <- c(doc_a = "In our last meeting, someone said that we are meeting again tomorrow",
       doc_b = "It's better to be good at being the best")
anno <- udpipe(x, "english")
anno[, c("doc_id", "sentence_id", "token", "lemma", "upos")]
#>    doc_id sentence_id    token    lemma  upos
#> 1   doc_a           1       In       in   ADP
#> 2   doc_a           1      our       we  PRON
#> 3   doc_a           1     last     last   ADJ
#> 4   doc_a           1  meeting  meeting  NOUN
#> 5   doc_a           1        ,        , PUNCT
#> 6   doc_a           1  someone  someone  PRON
#> 7   doc_a           1     said      say  VERB
#> 8   doc_a           1     that     that SCONJ
#> 9   doc_a           1       we       we  PRON
#> 10  doc_a           1      are       be   AUX
#> 11  doc_a           1  meeting     meet  VERB
#> 12  doc_a           1    again    again   ADV
#> 13  doc_a           1 tomorrow tomorrow  NOUN
#> 14  doc_b           1       It       it  PRON
#> 15  doc_b           1       's       be   AUX
#> 16  doc_b           1   better   better   ADJ
#> 17  doc_b           1       to       to  PART
#> 18  doc_b           1       be       be   AUX
#> 19  doc_b           1     good     good   ADJ
#> 20  doc_b           1       at       at SCONJ
#> 21  doc_b           1    being       be   AUX
#> 22  doc_b           1      the      the   DET
#> 23  doc_b           1     best     best   ADJ
lemmatisation <- paste.data.frame(anno, term = "lemma", 
                                  group = c("doc_id", "sentence_id"))
lemmatisation
#>   doc_id sentence_id
#> 1  doc_a           1
#> 2  doc_b           1
#>                                                             lemma
#> 1 in we last meeting , someone say that we be meet again tomorrow
#> 2                          it be better to be good at be the best

library(SnowballC)
tokens   <- strsplit(x, split = "[[:space:][:punct:]]+")
stemming <- lapply(tokens, FUN = function(x) wordStem(x, language = "en"))
stemming
#> $doc_a
#>  [1] "In"       "our"      "last"     "meet"     "someon"   "said"    
#>  [7] "that"     "we"       "are"      "meet"     "again"    "tomorrow"
#> 
#> $doc_b
#>  [1] "It"     "s"      "better" "to"     "be"     "good"   "at"     "be"    
#>  [9] "the"    "best"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lemmatization can be done in R easily with textStem package.
Steps are:
1) Install textstem
2) Load the package by 
       `library(textstem)`
3) `stem_word=lemmatize_words(word, dictionary = lexicon::hash_lemmas)`
     where stem_word is the result of lemmatization and word is the input word.

Comment: That's not really a very good code example.  It's not even formatted properly.  How do you apply it to a VCorpus object?