# Lemmatization in R

Tags: r, text-analysis, lemmatization

I am new to this text analysis,
I have prepared one corpus, I want to Lemmatize words in corpus, is there any way we can do it using R

It will be really a great help if anyone able to share script which help me to lemmatize words in corpus

I am seearching a lot but unable to get solutions I noticed library like koRpus and wordnet but unable to replicate syntax shared online site and in document

Comment: Use `Treetagger` in `koRpus`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform Lemmatization in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214148/how-to-perform-lemmatization-in-r)