# steamming words with r

Tags: r, nlp, tm, snowball

I'm having a difficulties to understand R stemming word process.

In my example, i created the following corpus object

```
a <- Corpus(VectorSource("device so much more funand  unlike most android torrent download clients"))
```

So a is

```
a[[1]]$content

[1] "device so much more funand  unlike most android torrent download clients"
```

The first word in this string is "device", I created my term matrix

```
b <- TermDocumentMatrix(a, control = list(stemming = TRUE))
```

and got this as an output

```
dimnames(b)$Terms
[1] "android"  "client"   "devic"    "download" "funand"   "more"     "most"      "much"     "torrent" 
[10] "unlik"
```

What i like to know is why i lost the "e" at "device" and "unlike" but did not loss it at "more".

how can i avoid this from happening in this word and in some others?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the documentation for the Porter stemmer. This is off-topic on SO: use [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Porter+stemmer). Unless you actually want to write a custom stemmer, which is a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the [MorphAdorner](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/lemmatizer/example/) lemmatizer at Northwestern University. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993796/lemmatizer-in-r-or-python-am-are-is-be/22994954#22994954) has the code for the `lemmatize(...)` function.

```
library(tm)
a     <- Corpus(VectorSource("device so much more funand  unlike most android torrent download clients"))
words <- Terms(TermDocumentMatrix(a))
lemmatize(words)
#    android    clients     device   download     funand       more       most       much    torrent     unlike 
#  "android"   "client"   "device" "download"   "funand"     "more"     "most"     "much"  "torrent"   "unlike"
```

As you can see, it removes the "s" from "clients" but not the "e" from "device".

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the `tm` and `SnowballC` packages.

Stemming in these packages works using the [Porter Stemming algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/porter/stemmer.html) (in English).

If you want to play around with stemming algorithms, you can run:

```
getStemLanguages()
```

and try using others - The only other English built in is here:

```
wordStem(words, language = "english")
```

Which for your data, returns the same:

```
 [1] "android"  "client"   "devic"    "download" "funand"   "more"     "most"     "much"     "torrent" 
[10] "unlik"
```